# How to play a single note of every chord in a MIDI file (one of 4 voices in a song)?

Tags: android, kotlin, midi, audio-player

i have this code to play a midi file (this is the function that exactly prepares the midi to play):

```
fun getFile() {
    val assets = assets
    val assetFileDescriptor = assets.openFd("midi/${DataManager.songNumber}.mid")

    // Create a MediaPlayer object and set its data source to the MIDI file.
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
    mediaPlayer?.setDataSource(assetFileDescriptor.fileDescriptor, assetFileDescriptor.startOffset, assetFileDescriptor.length)
    mediaPlayer?.prepare()

    binding.progressSlider!!.valueTo = mediaPlayer?.duration?.toFloat() ?: 0F
    binding.progressSlider!!.valueFrom = 0F

    // Set the audio stream type to STREAM_MUSIC so that the audio is played through the speakers.
    val audioManager = getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
    audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL)
    audioManager.setStreamVolume(
        AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(
            AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), 0)

    mediaPlayer?.setOnCompletionListener {
        mediaPlayer?.stop()
        isPlaying = false
    }
}
```

And here's the code of the whole activity:

```
package com.mayonnaise.mysongbook4

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.media.AudioManager
import android.media.MediaPlayer
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.KeyEvent
import android.view.View
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.CompositePageTransformer
import androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
import com.mayonnaise.mysongbook4.databinding.ActivitySongviewBinding
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext

class SongView : AppCompatActivity() {

   private lateinit var binding: ActivitySongviewBinding
   private var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = null
   var isPlaying = false
   var currentPosition = 0

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding = ActivitySongviewBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val view = binding.root
    setContentView(view)

    val songDao = SongbookDatabase.getInstance(this).songDao()
    val inputMethodManager = getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager

    var songNumber = DataManager.songNumber

    binding.getNumber.textSize = DataManager.textSize-3
    binding.buttonGo.textSize = DataManager.textSize-6

    fun goToNumber(){
        binding.getNumberLayout.error = null
        var previousSongNumber = songNumber
        var number = binding.getNumber.text.toString()

        if (number.isNotEmpty()){
            if(number.toInt() < DataManager.maxSongNumber && number.toInt() > 0){
                songNumber = number.toInt()

                var side = when{
                    songNumber > previousSongNumber -> binding.viewPager.width.toFloat()
                    songNumber < previousSongNumber -> -binding.viewPager.width.toFloat()
                    else -> 0F
                }

                binding.getNumber.text?.clear()
                inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.currentFocus!!.windowToken, 0)

                binding.viewPager.animate()
                    .translationX(-side) // Move the ViewPager to the left
                    .setDuration(150L)
                    .withEndAction {
                        binding.viewPager.setCurrentItem(songNumber - 1, false) // Set the new page
                        binding.viewPager.translationX = side
                        binding.viewPager.animate()
                            .translationX(0f) // Animate back to its original position
                            .setDuration(150L)
                            .start()
                    }
                    .start()

            }
            else{
                binding.getNumberLayout.error = getString(R.string.errorNumber)
            }
        }
        else{
            binding.getNumberLayout.error = getString(R.string.errorNumberEmpty)
        }
    }

    binding.viewPager.apply {
        clipChildren = false
        clipToPadding = false
        offscreenPageLimit = 3
    }

    binding.getNumber.onFocusChangeListener = View.OnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
        inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS, 0)
    }

    val compositePageTransformer = CompositePageTransformer()

    compositePageTransformer.addTransformer { page, position ->
        val r = 1 - kotlin.math.abs(position)
        page.scaleY = (0.95f + r * 0.05f)
    }

    binding.viewPager.setPageTransformer(compositePageTransformer)

    lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
        val allSongs = SongViewPagerAdapter(songDao.getAllSongsBySongbook(DataManager.chosenSongbook), lifecycleScope, applicationContext, false, "")
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
            binding.viewPager.animate()
                .alpha(0f)
                .setDuration(100L)
                .withEndAction {
                    binding.viewPager.adapter = allSongs
                    binding.viewPager.setCurrentItem(songNumber-1, false)
                    binding.viewPager.animate()
                        .alpha(1f)
                        .setDuration(100L)
                        .start()
                }
                .start()
        }
    }

    binding.viewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
        override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
            super.onPageSelected(position)
            mediaPlayer?.stop()
            DataManager.songNumber = binding.viewPager.currentItem+1
            getFile()
            currentPosition = 0
            isPlaying = false

        }
    })

    binding.buttonGo.setOnClickListener {
        goToNumber()
    }

    binding.buttonShare.setOnClickListener {
        lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
            var song = songDao.getSongByNumber(DataManager.songNumber, DataManager.chosenSongbook)
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                val sharedText = """
                ${DataManager.chosenSongbookName}
                    
                ${song.text}

                _________________________________

                https://www.ksiegarniarlch.pl/
            
                - wysłano z aplikacji mySongbook.
                """.trimIndent()

                val sendIntent: Intent = Intent().apply {
                    action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
                    putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sharedText)
                    type = "text/plain"
                }

                val shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, null)
                startActivity(shareIntent)
            }
        }

    }

    binding.buttonReport.setOnClickListener {
        DataManager.isSongReported = true
        val sendReportActivity = Intent(this, SendReportActivity::class.java)
        this.startActivity(sendReportActivity)
    }

    binding.getNumber.setOnKeyListener(View.OnKeyListener { _, keyCode, event ->
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            val inputMethodManager = getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.currentFocus!!.windowToken, 0)
            goToNumber()
            return@OnKeyListener true
        }
        false
    })

    binding.buttonFirstSound?.setOnClickListener {
        mediaPlayer?.selectTrack(0)
        mediaPlayer?.start()
    }

    binding.buttonPlay?.setOnClickListener {
        if(!isPlaying){
            isPlaying = true
            mediaPlayer?.seekTo(currentPosition)
            mediaPlayer?.start()

        }
        else{
            isPlaying = false
            currentPosition = (mediaPlayer?.currentPosition ?: 0)
            mediaPlayer?.pause()

        }
    }
}
fun getFile() {
    val assets = assets
    val assetFileDescriptor = assets.openFd("midi/${DataManager.songNumber}.mid")

    // Create a MediaPlayer object and set its data source to the MIDI file.
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
    mediaPlayer?.setDataSource(assetFileDescriptor.fileDescriptor, 
    assetFileDescriptor.startOffset, assetFileDescriptor.length)
    mediaPlayer?.prepare()

    binding.progressSlider!!.valueTo = mediaPlayer?.duration?.toFloat() ?: 0F
    binding.progressSlider!!.valueFrom = 0F

    // Set the audio stream type to STREAM_MUSIC so that the audio is played through the speakers.
    val audioManager = getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
    audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL)
    audioManager.setStreamVolume(
        AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(
            AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC), 0)

    // Log a message to the console when the MIDI playback has finished.
    mediaPlayer?.setOnCompletionListener {
        mediaPlayer?.stop()
        currentPosition = 0
        isPlaying = false
    }
}
  override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    isPlaying = false
    mediaPlayer?.release()
  }
}
```

Here's the UI:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".SongView">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lineLayout3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#295D7B"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/lineLayout3">

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lineLayout13"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#295D7B"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout4"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="330dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/standard_bottom_sheet"
        style="@style/Widget.Material3.BottomSheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:behavior_hideable="false"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDragHandleView
            android:id="@+id/drag_handle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/getNumberLinearLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonShare"
                    style="?attr/materialIconButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
                    android:layout_weight="2.8"
                    android:scaleX="1.30"
                    android:scaleY="1.30"
                    android:textColorHighlight="#9E9797"
                    android:textColorLink="#888686"
                    app:icon="@drawable/baseline_share_24"
                    app:iconGravity="textStart"
                    app:iconSize="25sp" />


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonFirstSound"
                    style="?attr/materialIconButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
                    android:layout_weight="2.8"
                    android:scaleX="1.30"
                    android:scaleY="1.30"
                    android:textColorHighlight="#9E9797"
                    android:textColorLink="#888686"
                    app:icon="@drawable/baseline_music_note_24"
                    app:iconGravity="textStart"
                    app:iconSize="25sp" />

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/getNumberLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1.6"
                    app:errorEnabled="true">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/getNumber"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                        android:hint="nr. pieśni..."
                        android:inputType="number" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonGo"
                    style="?attr/materialIconButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
                    android:layout_weight="2.8"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:scaleX="1.35"
                    android:scaleY="1.35"
                    app:icon="@drawable/search_icon"
                    app:iconGravity="textStart"
                    app:iconSize="25sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1">

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/buttonPlay"
                        style="?attr/materialIconButtonFilledStyle"
                        android:layout_width="90dp"
                        android:layout_height="90dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="14dp"
                        app:icon="@drawable/baseline_play_arrow_24"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        app:iconSize="55dp"></Button>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                    <NumberPicker
                        android:id="@+id/rateNumberPicker"
                        android:layout_width="48dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="end"
                        android:layout_height="90dp"></NumberPicker>
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/rateTV"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Tempo"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
                    android:id="@+id/progressSlider"
                    app:labelBehavior="gone"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/channel1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:checked="true"
                        android:text="1"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/channel2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:checked="true"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:text="2"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/channel3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:checked="true"
                        android:text="3"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1">
                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/channel4"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="4"
                        android:checked="true"
                        android:textStyle="bold"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/buttonReport"
                    style="?attr/materialIconButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:scaleX="1.35"
                    android:scaleY="1.35"
                    android:textColorHighlight="#9E9797"
                    android:textColorLink="#888686"
                    app:icon="@drawable/baseline_report_24"
                    app:iconGravity="textStart"
                    app:iconSize="25sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and the Midi file has four voices written in the notes, it looks like this:

[image: Notes]

and, this code just plays all notes (all chords) and i need it to play only one, for example first note from every chord. Like this:

[image: Every first note of every chord]

how to play only one of the voices?